# Integration by parts of Wirtinger derivative

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, partial-derivative, integration-by-parts

As a physics student, I am currently trying to use Wirtinger derivatives in everyday work.
While the basics are clear and so far seem to make life considerably simpler, I am having trouble to see if integration by parts is possible as in the real case.

Transforming to real two-dimensional coordinates, I have come to the following conclusions:

$$
\int_D \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} \, g \, \mathrm{d}^2 z
= \int_{\partial D} f \, g \, \mathrm{d} \bar z
- \int_D f \, \frac{\partial g}{\partial z} \, \mathrm{d}^2 z
$$

$$
\int_D \frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar z} \, g \, \mathrm{d}^2 z
= \int_{\partial D} f \, g \, \mathrm{d} z
- \int_D f \, \frac{\partial g}{\partial \bar z} \, \mathrm{d}^2 z
$$

Are these correct? I would be glad for any help, and especially for references that cover this topic, as I could not find any.

Comment: aren't $z$ and $\bar{z}$ independent variables?

Comment: I take $f(z)$ to implicitly mean that $f$ can depend on both $z$ and $\bar z$

Comment: but f $\int \partial_{\bar{z}}f(z,\bar{z})dz\neq f(z) $ so your second equality can't be true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, there is no way that your suggested formulas can be true. Your integrals over $D$ contain $1$-forms, which is nonsense since you're integrating over the 2-dimensional $D$.

On the other hand, Stokes' theorem is still valid in the complex setting:
$$
\int_{\partial D} \omega = \int_{D} d\omega.
$$
Furthermore, $d = \partial + \bar\partial$ so if $\omega = f(z)g(z)\,dz$ you get
\begin{align*}
\int_{\partial D} f(z)g(z)\,dz &= \int_{D} d\big( f(z)g(z)\,dz \big) \\
&= \int_{D} \bar\partial\big( f(z)g(z)\,dz \big) \\
&= \int_D \Big( \frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar z}(z) g(z) + f(z)\frac{\partial g}{\partial \bar z}(z) \Big) d\bar z \wedge dz,
\end{align*}
where the second equality it true since $dz \wedge dz = 0$ (the $\partial$-term picks up a $dz$).

If you want derivatives with respect to $\bar z$ in the integral over $D$, apply Stokes' to $\int_{\partial D} f(z)g(z)\,d\bar z$ instead.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was sloppy with my $dz$ and $d^2 z$, I hope it's clearer now. Using such forms seems to be a very elegant way of handling these situations, I think I will have to learn about them next! One question: in a practical calculation, what would the integral over $d \bar z$ look like? Do I simply conjugate my integration variable?